# magento 1.8.0.0: custom admin path does not show up in local.xml

Tags: magento

I'm running Magento 1.8.0.0.
I've changed the location of my magento admin panel access URL as follows:

```
Magento Admin Panel -> System (tab) -> Configuration (left sidebar)
  -> ADVANCED (sidebar heading) -> Admin (sidebar subheading)
  -> Admin Base URL (main content heading) -> Use Custom Admin Path
```

Use Custom Admin Path: Yes
  Custom Admin Path: fooadmin
  (now access admin panel more securely via:
   `http://localhost/magento/index.php/fooadmin` ).

This works fine.

However I wanted to know where on the filesystem these changes are stored,
because accorind to this post:

http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-how-to-change-admin-url-path/

I should look in app/etc/local.xml

but after this change the file still contains a reference to admin,
which cannot be right since I now access my admin panel successfully
via `http::/localhost/magento/index.php/fooadmin`. The local.xml still
contains the following reference to admin:

```
<admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <frontName><![CDATA[admin]]></frontName>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
</admin>
```

Why???

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One is an internal route redirect/rewrite. Uses the Db to save your changes.

The other (local.xml) is a more *'hardcoded'* value. It is normally set on install.

The file local.xml is created on install. If you remove it, Mage should prompt you to install again.

EDIT for more info. If I'm not mistaken code you are looking for is in `collectRoutes` method in `Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Admin` class. It uses XML node named in  `Mage_Adminhtml_Helper_Data::XML_PATH_CUSTOM_ADMIN_PATH` to get the custom path and sets in place of the current loaded path. ( If `Mage_Adminhtml_Helper_Data::XML_PATH_USE_CUSTOM_ADMIN_PATH` is `true` ).

Comment: So the value in the database overrides the value in local.xml? Thanks.

Comment: I thought local.xml overrides all other xml files on the filesystem, but was not aware of database values that override local.xml. Could you please provide some pointers (besides the source code)? Thanks.

Comment: @JohnSonderson: Lots of things can override the .xml files. Take a look at the files I named for one example.